# Adding a range price filter

Tags: django

I'm trying to add a range price filter for a list of products  with django and I'm having some trouble with how to proceed

Here's the code for the template : ( produits.html )

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var user = '{{request.user}}'
      function getToken(name)
      {
        var cookieValue = null;
        if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
            var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
            for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
              var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
              if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                 cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                break;
              }
            }
          }
        return cookieValue;
      }
      var csrftoken = getToken('csrftoken');
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    {% block content %}
    <div class="bg-light py-3">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12 mb-0"><a href="{% url 'index' %}">Home</a> <span class="mx-2 mb-0">/</span> <strong class="text-black">Shop</strong></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="site-section">
      <div class="container">

        <div class="row mb-5">
          <div class="col-md-9 order-2">
            <ul class="nav nav-pills flex-column mb-md-3">
                <li class="nav-item">
                  <div class="nav-link active">Les Produits :</div>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="row mb-5">
                {% for item in prod %}
              <div class="col-sm-6 col-lg-4 mb-4" data-aos="fade-up">
                <div class="block-4 text-center border">
                  <figure class="block-4-image">
                    <a href="#"><img src="{{item.imageURL}}" alt="Image placeholder" class="img-fluid"></a>
                  </figure>
                  <div class="block-4-text p-4">
                    <p class="text-primary font-weight-bold">{{item.nom}}</p>
                    <p class="mb-0">{{item.description}}</p>
                    <p class="text-primary font-weight-bold">{{item.prix}}</p>
                    <button data-product="{{item.id}}" data-action="add" class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-btn update-cart"> Add to Cart</button>
                    <a href="#" class="btn btn-outline-secondary add-btn">View</a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
              {% endfor %}
            </div>
            <div class="row" data-aos="fade-up">
              <div class="col-md-12 text-center">
                <div class="site-block-27">
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="col-md-3 order-1 mb-5 mb-md-0">
            <div class="border p-4 rounded mb-4">
              <h3 class="mb-3 h6 text-uppercase text-black d-block">Categories</h3>
              <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0">
                {% for i in categ %}
                <li class="mb-1"><a href="#" class="d-flex"><span>{{i.nom}}</span> <span class="text-black ml-auto">{{nb}}</span></a></li>
                {% endfor %}
              </ul>
            </div>

            <div class="border p-4 rounded mb-4">
              <div class="mb-4">
                <h3 class="mb-3 h6 text-uppercase text-black d-block">Filter by Price</h3>
                <div id="slider-range" class="border-primary"></div>
                <input type="text" name="PRICE" id="amount" class="form-control border-0 pl-0 bg-white" disabled="" />



              </div>

              <div class="mb-4">
                <h3 class="mb-3 h6 text-uppercase text-black d-block">Size</h3>
                <label for="s_sm" class="d-flex">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="s_sm" class="mr-2 mt-1"> <span class="text-black">Small (2,319)</span>
                </label>
                <label for="s_md" class="d-flex">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="s_md" class="mr-2 mt-1"> <span class="text-black">Medium (1,282)</span>
                </label>
                <label for="s_lg" class="d-flex">
                  <input type="checkbox" id="s_lg" class="mr-2 mt-1"> <span class="text-black">Large (1,392)</span>
                </label>
              </div>

              <div class="mb-4">
                <h3 class="mb-3 h6 text-uppercase text-black d-block">Color</h3>
                <a href="#" class="d-flex color-item align-items-center" >
                  <span class="bg-danger color d-inline-block rounded-circle mr-2"></span> <span class="text-black">Red (2,429)</span>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="d-flex color-item align-items-center" >
                  <span class="bg-success color d-inline-block rounded-circle mr-2"></span> <span class="text-black">Green (2,298)</span>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="d-flex color-item align-items-center" >
                  <span class="bg-info color d-inline-block rounded-circle mr-2"></span> <span class="text-black">Blue (1,075)</span>
                </a>
                <a href="#" class="d-flex color-item align-items-center" >
                  <span class="bg-primary color d-inline-block rounded-circle mr-2"></span> <span class="text-black">Purple (1,075)</span>
                </a>
              </div>

            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="site-section site-blocks-2">
                <div class="row justify-content-center text-center mb-5">
                  <div class="col-md-7 site-section-heading pt-4">
                    <h2>Categories</h2>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-4 mb-lg-0" data-aos="fade" data-aos-delay="">
                    <a class="block-2-item" href="#">
                      <figure class="image">
                        <img src="{%static 'images/women.jpg' %}" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                      </figure>
                      <div class="text">
                        <span class="text-uppercase">Collections</span>
                        <h3>Women</h3>
                      </div>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-5 mb-lg-0" data-aos="fade" data-aos-delay="100">
                    <a class="block-2-item" href="#">
                      <figure class="image">
                        <img src="{%static 'images/children.jpg' %}" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                      </figure>
                      <div class="text">
                        <span class="text-uppercase">Collections</span>
                        <h3>Children</h3>
                      </div>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                  <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-6 col-lg-4 mb-5 mb-lg-0" data-aos="fade" data-aos-delay="200">
                    <a class="block-2-item" href="#">
                      <figure class="image">
                        <img src="{%static 'images/men.jpg' %}" alt="" class="img-fluid">
                      </figure>
                      <div class="text">
                        <span class="text-uppercase">Collections</span>
                        <h3>Men</h3>
                      </div>
                    </a>
                  </div>
                </div>
              
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
      </div>
    </div>
    <script src="{%static 'js/cart.js' %}"></script>
    {% endblock content %}
  </body>
</html>
```

Here's the model code for products :

```
class Product(models.Model):
    nom = models.CharField(max_length=200,null= True, blank=True)
    prix = models.DecimalField(max_digits=7,decimal_places=2,null=True,blank=True)
    description = models.TextField(null=True,blank=True)
    nbr_stock = models.IntegerField(null=True,blank=True,default=0)
    image= models.ImageField(null=True,blank=True)
    taille= models.CharField(max_length=5,null=True,blank=True)
    categorie=models.CharField(max_length=200,null= True, blank=True)
    @property
    def imageURL(self):
        try :
            url = self.image.url
        except : 
            url = ''
        return url
    def __str__(self):
        return self.nom
```

My question is how can I "retrieve" the value from the range slider and then show the products according to the price? thank you in advance

Comment: Not sure if that's all you have to the `html` code. But for the price range slider, do you have two `input fields` or just one?

Comment: Hello ! i added the full html code, I have only one input field :D